# Block animations - how to cycle an array of UIImage

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

I'm going the direction of block animations, having tried to implement multiple animations and an "on finish" event with UIImageView animations but failing.

I have a UIImage array, which I need to cycle backwards through, displaying as I go.  Here is what I have so far:

```
__block int i = 9;
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                 animations:^{
                     self.fooView.image = fooImage[i];
                     [self.view addSubview:self.fooView];
                     i--;
                }
                 completion:NULL];
```

This does happily display the 9th element of fooImage[], but it doesn't iterate through the rest.

Is this a misunderstanding about what blocks can actually do in this context? I tried to also wrap a while loop, decrementing "i", but I ended up with the first element only (I sort of expected that).  How should one iterate through an array in this instance - perhaps have 9 different animation blocks?

Any tips will be gratefully received, and thanks for your time

sc.

Comment: Why don't you just use UIImageView animations? Do you need a transition between each image?

Comment: I wouldn't use a C array for an array of images. I would rather use an NSArray.

Comment: @jtbandes - Thanks for your suggestions, but I am coming from a UIImageView point of view, which I was unable to find a workable solution for.  You replied the that particular thread with a suggestion of KVO i think.  Cheers

Comment: @dasdom - thanks - I also have used an NSArray, but the image was blank/null when I pulled out with objectAtIndex:  Obviously something sinister is afoot in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Your animations completion handler is NULL, which means nothing is happened after animation is completed.
And it's strange to use animations block if you actually animate nothing. Animations won't wait 4 seconds before calling competition handler if there is nothing to animate.

```
__block int i = 9;
void(^process)(void(^recursive)());
process = ^(void(^recursive)()) {
    --i;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                     animations:^{
                         NSLog(@"%d", i);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         recursive(recursive);
                     }];
};
process(process);
```

Comment: This is really bizarre and kind of messy. Also, wouldn't passing a `void(^)(void(^)())` into a parameter of the type `void(^)()` cause a compiler warning or error?